# How to use size classes to set UIImageView object in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode6, size-classes

I am working on an universal application, and in that I am using 'size classes' for setting images in UIImageView.
I have tried it but it is looking same in size on iPhone and iPad.

[image]

Comment: Autolayout and UIimageView.contentMode option might help you
http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Comment: Can you explain it some more? At some extent it depends on actual size of the image which you are using for setting in UIImageView. And if size difference is much then you can use separate images and set it conditionally.

Answer (score 0):

you just have to give the your UIImageview size of your UIView and than set its ContentMode to AspectFit like these...i hope it helps..

```
imgView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
[imgView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
[self.view addSubview:imgView];
```

Comment: if you want image to align in top left than use these UIViewContentModeTopLeft or try out other ContentMode according to your need it may helps you..

Answer (score 0):

First you need to switch to different size classes for iPhone and iPad

add an imageView in **Size Class any any** so that it is available in any size classes

use **width compact** and **height regular** **Size Class** for **iPhone**

use **width regular** and **height regular** for **iPad**

In both size classes add constraints **leading, trailing, top, bottom**.

These constraints are for background image. For others you will have to change it as per your requirement.

I hope you already have different images for iPhone and iPad including retina images.

Comment: Be specific to your question...Cannot explain you every single step.

Answer (score 0):

- Set size class with respect to device and oritentation
- You can take help to change size classes from the following link
  [Size class base on different devices](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LayoutandAppearance.html)
  [How change size classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/SelectingASizeClass.html)
- Set constraints for leading, trailing, top and bottom constraint you can also set height and width constraints based on your requirement.
- Share your email i will email you a demo application for this using your image